# javac: invalid flag: .getting error when compiling a java servlet

Tags: java, servlets, jboss, javac

i run command

```
javac -classpath /home/coolhunk/JBoss/jboss-6.0.0.Final/common/lib/jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec.jar -d helloapp.war/WEB-INF/classes -sourcepath src/com/manning/jbia/intro/*
```

for generating java class files.but i am getting error

```
javac: invalid flag: src/com/manning/jbia/intro/HelloWorldServlet.java~
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use -help for a list of possible options
```

can anyone please point out what is the mistake in this command ??

Answer (score 1):

Try these commands using tomcat, place your servlet source in src folder and run these,

```
C:\Documents and Settings\ssit>cd C:\src

C:\src>javac -classpath "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0\
lib\servlet-api.jar" MyServlet.java
```

you can get the class file for the servlet. After getting the class file make the war file.

Answer (score 1):

```
javac -classpath /home/coolhunk/JBoss/jboss-6.0.0.Final/common/lib/jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec.jar -d helloapp.war/WEB-INF/classes -sourcepath src/com/manning/jbia/intro/*
```

The problem is the last item. The wildcard causes it to be expanded into everything in the directory, which causes everything after the first expansion to be treated as a source file name. The expansions also appear to include src/com/manning/jbia/intro/HelloWorldServlet.java~, which the compiler doesn't want to know about.

Try this:

```
javac -classpath /home/coolhunk/JBoss/jboss-6.0.0.Final/common/lib/jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec.jar -d helloapp.war/WEB-INF/classes -sourcepath src src/com/manning/jbia/intro/*.java
```